# How to reconstruct the dependence of the potential from a coordinate?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, potential-energy

An ion moves along the x-axis of a black box with a speed $V$ and returns in a time
$$T=a V^b$$
where $a$ and $b$ are some known constants. Having this, can we reproduce the dependence of a field potential $U(x)$ of this box?

So far I have managed to do this:

Adding to an initial velocity some $dV$ we get the increase in a time $dt$ and so $$T+dt=a (V+dV)^b \, .$$
We can derive $dt$ by subtracting the initial $T$ value
$$dt=a(V+dV)^b-aV^b \, .$$
Using the equivalence formula for $dV$ approaching zero we find
$$dt=aV^b(1+b\frac{dV}{V})-aV^b=abV^{b-1}dV \, .$$
We can find the acceleration
$$\frac{dV}{dt}=\frac{V^{1-b}}{ab} \, .$$

Similarly, as $V=(T/a)^{\frac{1}{b}}$ we have
\begin{align}
dV
&= \left(\frac{T+dt}{a} \right)^\frac{1}{b}
 - \left(\frac{T}{a} \right)^\frac{1}{b} \\
&= \left(\frac{T}{a} \right)^\frac{1}{b} \left(1+\frac{dt}{bT} \right) - \left( \frac{T}{a} \right)^\frac{1}{b} \\
&=\frac{T^\frac{1-b}{b}dt}{ab} \, .
\end{align}
This yields again
$$\frac{dV}{dt}=\frac{T^\frac{1-b}{b}}{ab} \, .$$
Now I assume it is our acceleration which the field imparts to the particle, thus
$$\frac{dV}{dt}=\frac{f}{m}=\frac{dU}{dx m} \, .$$
From there I am not sure whether or not I can integrate the equation
$$dU=m\frac{T^{\frac{1-b}{b}}}{ab} \, dx \, .$$
So, are the time $T$ there is a constant in relation to $dx$ or not? The answer I get from the last equation is
$$U(x)=U(0)+m\frac{T^{\frac{1-b}{b}}}{ab}x \, .$$
I am confused by two things here:

1. The difference between the answers derived from the second and the first approach:
   $$\frac{dV}{dt} = \frac{V^{1-b}}{ab} \quad \text{and} \quad \frac{dV}{dt} = \frac{T^\frac{1-b}{b}}{ab}$$
2. The possibility of integrating that way.

Are there other ways to get the definite answer for this task?

Answer (score 1):

No, I don't think that you proceed correctly. You need the relationship between force and distance, and this is what you should integrate.

So, please follow my formulas. So, I understand that $V$ is the velocity of the ion (not of the box).
From your formula $T=aV^b$, I deduce the acceleration $A$ acquired at the end of the trip, **by assuming something that is not written in the exercise**, that inside the box the velocity obeys the same rule as we see at the end of the box. As Lionel says, between $v = V$ and $v = 0$ passes only half of the time, $T_1 = T/2$, s.t.

$$V=\left( \frac{2T_1}{a}\right)^{1/b} \Longrightarrow \, \, A= \frac{dV}{dT_1} = 2^{1/b}\frac{1}{ab} \left( \frac{T_1}{a}\right)^{1/b-1}$$

Given the acceleration, the force is $F = mA$, as you say.

Now, you have to calculate the space that the ion travelled inside the box.

$$ X = \int_0 ^{T_1} V \ dT' = 2^{1/b}a\int_0 ^{T_1} \frac {dT'}{a} \ \left( \frac{T'}{a}\right)^{1/b} = 2^{1/b}\frac {ab}{1 + b} \ \ \left( \frac{T_1}{a}\right)^{(1+b)/b}.$$

Now you can express the force as a function of $X$ by eliminating between them the time $T_1$, and then integrate and find the potential. Let's do it:

$$\left( \frac{T_1}{a}\right) = 2^{-1/b}\left( \frac {1+b}{ab} X\right) ^{b/(1+b)}$$

Substituting in the field strength $E = mA/q$, where $q$ is the charge of the ion,

$$ E = 2^{-1/b} \frac {m}{q} \frac {1}{ab} \left( \frac {1+b}{ab} X\right) ^{(1-b)/(1+b)}$$

This can be easily integrated over $X$

$$U(X) = 2^{1-1/b} \frac {1+b}{ab} \frac {m}{q} \left( \frac {1+b}{ab} \right) ^{(1-b)/(1+b)} X^{2/(1+b)} $$

$$ = 2^{1 -1/b} \frac {m}{q} \left( \frac {1+b}{ab} X \right) ^{2/(1+b)} $$

Answer (score 0):

As it follows from the Mechanics by Landau-Lifshitz (which can be found [here](https://ia601205.us.archive.org/11/items/Mechanics_541/LandauLifshitz-Mechanics.pdf) — page 28), the desired dependence can be found in the form of

$$x(U)=\frac{1}{2\pi \sqrt{2m}}\int_{0}^{U} \frac{T(E)dE}{\sqrt{U-E}}$$

Where $T(E)$ from the law of conservation of energy and the initial statement $T_{½}=\alpha V^\beta$

$$T(E)=2\alpha (\frac{2E}{m})^\frac{\beta}{2}$$

The period $T$ given there is twice as big as a time of return $T_{½}$ due to the fact, that ion has done only a half of its full way by the time it returns to initial point.

From now I am not familiar with methods of integrating such equations, so I have used Mathematica database for this purpose (please, let me know if the answer is wrong, for I cannot make sure that the answer is correct):

$$U(x)=\frac{1}{2}m \left ( \frac{2x\pi}{\alpha}\right ) ^{\frac{2}{\beta+1}}\frac{\Gamma(\frac{\beta+3}{2})}{\Gamma(\frac{\beta+3}{2})}$$

$\Gamma$ here is a gamma function. Note that the answer $U(x)$ is dimensionally correct.

Comment: Are you sure $T$ here is multiplied by 2, or is it just the period?

Comment: @lionelbrits Yes, I should have marked that the period is actually twice as big as the time needed for ion to return from $x_0$ through $x_1$ back to $x_0$. It is the same situation as in the case of a simple pendulum.